# Contact photo is stretched while set into an ImageView

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch phone contacts image and set into an ImageView .I am getting the image, but when I try to set the image into an ImageView it is pixelated.

**The code for fetching the image**

```
String select = "(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " == \"" + name + "\" )";
    Cursor c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
    startManagingCursor(c);

    if (c.moveToNext()) {
         idValue = c.getString(0);
    InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                        ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(idValue)));

 if (inputStream != null) {
  photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
  contact_image.setImageBitmap(photo);
 }
}
```

I want to show the details of contacts , Because of that i try fetch the Contact ID by name.

Layout.xml

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contact_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/un_known_avtar" />
```

Comment: in your xml file make your **imageview** `width` and `height` as `wrap_content` because if your image resolution is smaller than your imageviews dimension it will going to strect

Comment: I suggest you to remove `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`.

Answer (score 0):

As sud suggests in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794981/contact-photo-is-stretched-while-set-into-an-imageview#comment55356693_33794981), change your `ImageView` code in layout.xml.

1. Set `layout_width` & `layout_height` to `wrap_content`
2. Remove `layout_alignParentLeft` and `layout_alignParentRight`
3. Remove the `scaleType` tag

Result:

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/contactimage" />
```